# perform scroll using AccessibilityNodeInfo in AccessibilityService

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

i want to Scroll the current screen.
i tried this 
`AccessibilityNodeInfo accessibilityNodeInfo=getRootInActiveWindow();
accessibilityNodeInfo.addAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.AccessibilityAction.ACTION_SCROLL_DOWN);`

but i always say "Cannot perform this action on a sealed instance".
help please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: The problem with what you're trying to do.

When you see this

> Cannot perform this action on a sealed instance.

This message is Android telling you that the information you have is set. Does it make sense for you to be able to tell a view, that is not scrollable, that it is?  NO. You CAN NOT force a view to be scrollable.  A view being scrollable is up to the view. For example, a Button being scrollable makes no sense! An accessibility service can't force this behavior.

It is very likely that the root node of an application is some type of frame layout, and will never be scrollable. The scrollable portion of the hierarchy is almost always a child of the main layout/root view. Moral of the story, you can't tell a view to be scrollable, you must find a scrollable view.

This being said, I'm going to give you a much better solution for this, hopefully it is within the range of devices that you support.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public boolean scrollTo(AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo) {

    return nodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.AccessibilityAction.ACTION_SHOW_ON_SCREEN.getId());

}
```

If you need to support versions befor Android M, what you need to do is explore the AccessibilityNodeInfo Hierarchy for the view within the layout where this is true, this would look approximate like this (Not tested, but should be very close!):

```
public boolean scrollView(AccessibilityNodeInfo nodeInfo) {

    if (nodeInfo == null) return false;

    if (nodeInfo.isScrollable()) {
        return nodeInfo.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SCROLL_FORWARD);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeInfo.getChildCount(); i++) {
        if (scrollView(nodeInfo.getChild(i)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Check my question please i edit.
No i don't want to support Android M i want to do this on Android-O

Comment: But when there are four options for scroll scroll up and down left ,right it performs scroll left and right .but i want to perform up and down what should i do for that?
otherwise in two options it work great.

Comment: The better solution will work in Android O as well.  The @TargetApi is a "minimum" not an exact.  Try that approach.

Comment: Also, don't change questions so drammatically.  Ask a new question, and link to it.  This answer is the correct answer for your old question.  Please revert to that, and bundle you new concerns in a new question.